# Get Guest built-in account name in C#

Tags: c#, administrator, system-administration

I want to get `Guest` built-in account name with C#. Because language is different on different regions and Guest is only for English version of Windows and for example, on Spanish Windows, Guest is `Invitado`.
What I want to do is get the name and edit the account with that name I get, Like setting password or add some groups to it.

I already tried this code:

```
            var sGuest = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AccountGuestSid, null);
            PrincipalContext systemContext = null;
            systemContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
            guestPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(systemContext, IdentityType.Name, sGuest.ToString());
```

And I get this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'The domainSid parameter must be specified for creating well-known SID of type AccountGuestSid.
```

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the Display&Login Name is different from the name in the FileSystem. i.e., if I rename a user, often the users Profile folder will keep the old name. It simply can not be moved/renamed without risking issues. | For Guest however, there should be a special variable to check. It should be marked with something like `isGuestAccount = true` or something like that.

Comment: Another issue is that sometimes folder names are localized, but only when viewed in the explorer. The folder for the Profiles is "Users". It is written into the File System as "Users". But it is displayed as Users or Benutzer (German), usuario(Spanish, I hope) or anything like else localized.

Comment: Yes thats all true, I just want to get the name of Guest user from that region as I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SID of the local guest account takes the form `S-1-5-21domain-501`, where `domain` is the SID of the machine.  Because the domain SID is required to construct the guest account SID, the constructor to `SecurityIdentifier` fails if the `domainSid` parameter is null. You can get the machine SID via WMI and pass that as the `domainSid` argument to the `SecurityIdentifier` constructor.

Alternatively, it is possible to obtain the guest account without the machine SID.  One method for doing so is to use a `PrincipalSearcher` to identify the user account whose SID is that of the well known guest account SID, and query its `Name` property to get the local name of the account:

```
// using System.Security.Principal;
// using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine)))
                .FindAll()
                .Single(a => a.Sid.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.AccountGuestSid))
                .Name // returns the local account name, e.g., 'Guest'
```

Comment: how can I contact you? I have some questions if you are available